# clicking on a item on action bar go to setting

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am building a android app.I have created a action bar.with a item say click.
In menu.xml file I have this code for the item

```
 <item android:id="@+id/setting"
      android:title="Settings"
      android:icon="@drawable/setting"
      android:showAsAction="always"/>
```

Now I want to click this item and the page should go to next activity by sliding to left.for that I tried writing function on click as follows.

```
 <item android:id="@+id/setting"
      android:title="Settings"
      android:icon="@drawable/setting"
      android:showAsAction="always"
      android:onclick="Nameoffunction"/>
```

But as i write this one line and try to run the application on emulator without writing the body of the function It shows unexpectedly closed your app.

Can any body tell me how to do this sliding to next activity on a item click on action bar.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you register the new activity in your manifest file? Android needs to know in advance all of the activities that your app uses. If your intent to create a new activity is not listed in your app's manifest, it will crash.

Add the new activity in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
    ...
    <activity android:name=".NameOfYourNewActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

Comment: before that activity creation.I need to call a function on that item click. How do i do that ?

Comment: May you post the body of the function in question?